# The tangent space $T_{(x,x)}(\triangle)$ is the diagonal of $T_x(X) \times T_x(X).$ - Is this proof legit?

Tags: differential-topology

> If $\triangle$ is the diagonal of $X \times X$, show that its tangent space $T_{(x,x)}(\triangle)$ is the diagonal of $T_x(X) \times T_x(X).$ Is the following proof legit?

- $T_{(x,x)} \Delta \subseteq \Delta \subseteq T_x X \times T_x X$

All tangent vectors at the point $(x,x)$ in $\Delta$ are described by velocity vectors of curves passing through $(x,x)$. Suppose $c(t)$ is a curve through $(x,x)$ such that $c(0) = (x,x)$, then the velocity vector is given by $c'(0)$. Any $c(t)$ that lies in the diagonal looks like $c(t) = (\gamma(t), \gamma(t))$, where $\gamma(t)$ is a curve in $X$ through the point $x$ i.e., $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\gamma'(0) = v \in T_x X$. Then $c'(t) = (\gamma'(t), \gamma'(t))$ and $c'(0) = (v,v) \in \Delta \subseteq T_x X \times T_x X$.

- $T_x X \times T_x X \subseteq \Delta \subseteq T_{(x,x)} \Delta$

All tangent vectors at the point $x$ in $X$ are described by velocity vectors of curves passing through $x$. Suppose $r(t)$ is a curve through $x$ such that $r(0) = x$, then the velocity vector is given by $r'(0)$. Any element that lies in $T_x \times T_x$ looks like $(r^\prime(t), r^\prime(t))$, which is element in $T_{x,x}(\Delta)$.

Thanks.

This question intends to fill in the answer for the question [GP 1.2.10(b) The tangent space $T_{(x,x)}(\triangle)$ is the diagonal of $T_x(X) \times T_x(X).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429609/gp-1-3-10b-the-tangent-space-t-x-x-triangle-is-the-diagonal-of-t-xx/433774?noredirect=1#433774) And I do realize this is a very popular question, here's another identical problem again with partial solution: [Show that the tangent space of the diagonal is the diagonal of the product of tangent space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413839/show-that-the-tangent-space-of-the-diagonal-is-the-diagonal-of-the-product-of-ta?rq=1).

Comment: Why did you post this as a question and not as an answer?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan that one only answered half. As I said at the end of the question, I intended to fill in that one...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan because i actually want to ask if my proof is correct...